How to include part of a source file in org-mode for export?
Org mode has a nice directive "#+INCLUDE" that allows me to include source code when I export to markdown.  It even let's you import part of the file by supplying line numbers.
However, when the file changes, line numbers quickly become out of date, so I'd rather have a solution where I can match the content.
The info manual suggests you can search using regular expressions, however I could not get this to work.
I tried e.g.
    #+INCLUDE: "test.js::/constructor/" src javascript 

However it will still just include the whole file.  Does anyone know a solution?

AFAIK, there is no provision for regexps in #+include constructs. Can you point out where you think you saw it?

https://orgmode.org/manual/Include-Files.html - Inclusions may specify a file-link to extract an object matched by org-link-search

...which does not mention regexps at all.

Okay, I was wrong: the Search Options link does mention regexps. Apologies.

Yeah.  However, it also mentions:
" (1) Note that ‘org-link-search-must-match-exact-headline’ is locally
bound to non-‘nil’.  Therefore, ‘org-link-search’ only matches headlines
and named elements. "
So, not sure what that means for source code - what is a "named element"? I am just confused why it is not working.  It seems like it should, but I could not find any examples online either.

I suspect that “named element” means an org element, e.g. src block, that was assigned a name using #+name: syntax. If you give an org element a name you can include or reference that named element in org files

Ah that might be what is meant then.  Unfortunately that does not help me in my case, since I don't think you can "name" elements in source code that way, can you?
